# mod_wsgi + apache not multithreaded, why?

Tags: python, apache, wsgi

WSGI application

```
# coding: utf-8

import time

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = str(time.time())
    time.sleep(5)
    output += ' -> ' + str(time.time())

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

Apache VirtualHost

```
    ServerName localhost

    WSGIDaemonProcess main user=www-data group=www-data processes=1 threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/main/main.wsgi

    
        WSGIProcessGroup main
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/main_error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/main_log common
```

Сonnecting multiple clients, they are processed sequentially, there is no multithreading. Why?

Comment: What apache package, specifically?

Comment: Supply the missing bits of your configuration which surround the WSGIProcessGroup. Am presuming it is missing, otherwise why is it indented. Also, what Apache MPM are you use and have you fiddled the MPM settings when you shouldn't have.

Answer (score 3):

This is being dealt with on mod_wsgi mailing list. See:

http://groups.google.com/group/modwsgi/browse_frm/thread/b8aaab6bfc4cca6d

Answer (score 1):

While not exactly an answer, I noticed the serial behavior with a similar setup when testing on a single browser with multiple tabs. ( i tried chrome7 and ff4 )

Wondering if it was the browser enforcing the serial-ness, I tried the same experiment with two separate browsers, and it definitely showed the server to be acting multi-threaded.

My setup was:
mod_wsgi 3.3-1
python 3.1.2-2
apache 2.2.17-1
on archlinux x86_64
tests were run with mod_wsgi in embedded mode.

hope it helps.